# Const as String HIGHVALUE in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I create in VBA a `String` `Const` as `HIGHVALUE`? In `Date` it is e.g. 31.12.9999.

```
Const HIGHVALUE As String = "zzz"
Dim test As String

test = "zzzz"
If test <= HIGHVALUE Then
    Debug.Print "equal or lower"
Else
    Debug.Print "higher"
End If
```

`test` is higher than `HIGHVALUE` => so `HIGHVALUE` is not the highest possible string => it prints `higher`.

Comment: You're comparing two strings using `<=`? Why not integers or doubles?

Comment: I dont understand what you're trying to do. Please Clarify.

Comment: I'm thinking about the possibility to have a `HIGHVALUE` in `String`. In `Long`, `Date`, etc. it's easy to do it, I have a specific problem and for solving this it would be good to have a `String` that is the highest possible String, so that all others are lower. Is there such a possibility?

Comment: the only possibility is the one suggested by Gustav, but you should know how long the string you compare with can be, that's the issue.

Comment: also if your string can contain special chars and not only letters, you are doomed with your zzzzz.. You should compare ASCII values instead

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "higher" and "lower". Strings aren't numerical. If you want to do a lexical comparison (position in the alphabet), then say so (but now it just looks like you're testing if a string doesn't or does contain at least 3 z's at the start).  If you want to compare length, however, this is all wrong.

Comment: I must admit I'm confused, it looks like your sample code does do what you are asking for

Comment: Where is the problem? I checked with my sample code if threre is a `String` value (with `test`), that is higher than `Const HIGHVALUE` - for this is the definition of a `HIGHVALUE`, that there could be not a higher value. In `Date` it is easy, there it is 31.12.9999.

Answer (score 1):

Set the length to above the maximum length you expect to test for, for example:

```
Const HIGHVALUE As String = "zzzzzzzz"
```

Comment: Should I use `z` as character, that is higher than every other possible character? What about the special characters?

Comment: If I have no special chars in `String`, this would be a good solution.

Comment: Yes, for standard ascii, _z_ will do.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to convert a `String` to numeric ASC, so that I could compare Strings then - anyway if there are special chars within or not:

```
Private Sub testGetASCValueOfString()

    Debug.Print GetASCValueOfString("&$%§()[]}")

End Sub

Private Function GetASCValueOfString(test As String) As Variant

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    GetASCValueOfString = 0
    j = 1
    For i = Len(test) To 1 Step -1
        GetASCValueOfString = GetASCValueOfString + Asc(Mid$(test, i, 1)) * (j * 256)
        j = j + 1
    Next i

End Function
```

=> The advantage is, that now I don't need to compare Strings or need a `String` `HIGHVALUE`, because all is numeric now.